# Purposes and priorities of Apache conf files

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've installed an Apache2 server on a Linux Box (Ubuntu 10.04 TLS) and am trying to setup some virtual host and proxies.  There is some stuff in the `apache2.conf`, an empty `httpd.conf` (which was used heavily in the Windows setup I had), and then there are the invidividual files for the websites in my `sites-available` directory, call them `a.com` and `b.com`.

What information needs to be where?
What is the priority of processing for these?
Will repeated information cause a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache configuration is exhaustively covered in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/) (though, if you're using Debian or Ubuntu, there are some [additional considerations](http://www.control-escape.com/web/configuring-apache2-debian.html)) and the best way to familiarize with Apache will be to study each portion of the documentation as you encounter a need to use a particular module or set of directives.

To address your specific questions:

> What information needs to be where?

The file system you described would suggest that your configuration is intended for [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) (the default [Ubuntu 10.04 Apache configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html)) so any directives which apply to your Apache configuration for *all* virtual hosts (i.e. domains, subdomains) should be added to `httpd.conf` and any directives specific to a given virtual host (including its declaration) should be added to the `/sites-available/domain.com.conf` (or similar) file.

> What is the priority of processing for these?

Toward the end of a typical `apache2.conf` file, the following directive appears:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

This directive instructs Apache to include all configuration files in the `sites-enabled` directory. (see [Include documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include))

Files are included in numeric then alphabetical order from 0-9 then A-z.

> Will repeated information cause a problem?

Duplicate virtual host definitions will be ignored when Apache is started, however, you will receive a warning when this happens - ideally, you should run `apache2ctl configtest` ([documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html#syntax)) before attempting to restart Apache so you have the opportunity to correct duplicates or errors which would prevent Apache from starting.

Note that the config syntax checker will *not* warn you if there are file permission problems or other issues which would prevent Apache from starting.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it's as exhaustive as it needs to be but you've helped answer most of what I needed to know.  So on a Linux system is `httpd.conf` ever used?

Comment: @Lance Roberts - Yes, `httpd.conf` is the default config file for Apache 1.x installations and the [Ubuntu Apache documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html) recommends putting global config directives there. I'll amend my answer to point to some Debian/Ubuntu-specific resources too - you're right that the Debian/Ubuntu nuances *aren't* documented at Apache.org